# Printing the bitmap image on ZPL label printer

Tags: zebra-printers

From the title you can see like, this problem had been discussed in past. I have taken the earlier posts as reference and tried to print the bitmap image on Zebra label printer. I am not able to print the image that i am looking for. Please dont ignore as it was discussed.

Please view code snippet mentioned below:

```
private string TestImage()
    {
        string filepath = Application.StartupPath + "\\ImageSymbols\\CSA.bmp";

        byte[] bitmapFileData = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);
        int fileSize = bitmapFileData.Length;

        // Retrieve the image.
        Bitmap image1 = new Bitmap(filepath, true);


        //Siva - Not in use
        Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(0, 0, image1.Width, image1.Height);
        System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bmpData1 =
        image1.LockBits(rect1, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
        image1.PixelFormat);



        //Gets the height and width of the bitmap file
        int bitmapDataHeight = image1.Height;
        int bitmapDataWidth = image1.Width;

        //Gets the size of the bitmap file
        long bitmapDataFileSize = new FileInfo(filepath).Length;


        //Gets the size of the bitmap file in integer
        int bitmapDataFileSizeInt = Convert.ToInt32(bitmapDataFileSize);

        //Gets the bitmap offset data in bytes. 
        byte[] test = bitmapFileData.Skip(10).Take(1).ToArray();

        //assigns the bitmap offset data to a array value
        byte bitmapDataOffset = test[0]; // i am getting offset value = 62

        //changes the bitmap offset data to a integer value
        int bitmapDataOffsetInt = Convert.ToInt32(bitmapDataOffset);

        //gets the bitmap data file size by subtracting the file size with the bitmap offset data size
        int bitmapDataSize = bitmapDataFileSizeInt - bitmapDataOffset;

        //int width = 80;
        //int height = 80;
        int bitsPerPixel = 1; // Monochrome image required!
        //int bitmapDataLength = 8160;

        double widthInBytes = Math.Ceiling(bitmapDataWidth / 8.0);


        // Copy over the actual bitmap data from the bitmap file.
        // This represents the bitmap data without the header information.
        byte[] bitmap = new byte[bitmapDataSize];
        //bmpData1
        Buffer.BlockCopy(bitmapFileData, bitmapDataOffset, bitmap, 0, bitmapDataSize);

        // Invert bitmap colors
        for (int i = 0; i < bitmapDataSize; i++)
        {
            bitmap[i] ^= 0xFF;
        }

        // Create ASCII ZPL string of hexadecimal bitmap data
        string ZPLImageDataString = BitConverter.ToString(bitmapFileData);
        ZPLImageDataString = ZPLImageDataString.Replace("-", string.Empty);

        string str = "";
        return str = "^XA^FO100,100^GFA," + //At Postion 100, 100
            bitmapDataSize.ToString() + "," +     // Total bytes of data to be placed
            bitmapDataSize.ToString() + "," +     // Total bytes of data to be placed, repeats as per API
            widthInBytes + "," + //
            ZPLImageDataString + "^XZ";
```

With the above sample code i am not able to print the bitmap image on Zibra label printer.
And i dont want to use the Zebra net bridge to convert the bmp to GRF image type.

Can any one suggest me on where i am making the mistake?
Is the way i am getting the offset value wrong? (Current its 62, dont know for my image its correct or not. can anyone suggest me the formula to find the bitmap image offset value)

Answer (score 0):

You can download the [Zebra SDK here](http://www.zebra.com/us/en/products-services/software/link-os/link-os-sdk.html) which has a library function to do this conversion and printing. There's a few phases it needs to go thru, dithering to get to 1-bit-per pixel black and white needs to happen first, and then resizing/scaling, then finally creating the ZPL for it. The SDK does all this stuff for you...

Comment: I tried to use the Zebra SDK, where i was facing problem on importing unmanaged dlls (Not able to extract the methods for those dlls, thirdparty tool restrictions). Is there any other way where i can modify the code so that i can resolve the problem of printing the bitmap image on RZ400 label printer. How can i do the scaling for given image? please help me in this.

Comment: I could able to print with the Help of Multiplatform SDK but the that wont solve my probelm as i have to prepare the ZPL command. As you commented that it my C# solution needs some scaling, can you please help me in solving that.